# When "NOT" to use ES6 arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Setting aside compatibility issues aside, when are we to use "function" and "=>"?  Are we to completely replace "function" with "=>" in es6 compatible environments?

I guess I can see when you want "this" to be different context you wouldn't want arrow.  But I genuinely don't see any other reason to use "function" keyword anymore and I would like to clarify this.

Comment: methods in object literals can't use them...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196

Comment: @dandavis What do you mean by that?

Comment: i mean that methods use `this`, and you can't use `this` in fat arrows like you can normal functions, so thing like `pretty:function(){return this.fName+" "+this.lName;},` don't work like you want them to.  Same goes for generic functions like `function sum(n){"use strict"; return n+this;}`, which i use all the time with map/filter, `ex: [1,2,3].map(sum, 5);`